# Schedule Plan Database Structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm working on a project where I need to design a system where the clients want to make tasks which has to be performed hourly/monthly/yearly/fortnightly etc with frequency

Ex Mop the floor daily twice ... clean the washrooms hourly once or once in two hours ... Clean the building facade once in every six months etc.

Is there a generic settings table that can take care of the logic behind every hourly monthly frequencies so that tomorrow client wants to add quarterly i dont have to hard code the logic behind quarterly

Elaborated Example :

```
Task                           Interval                Frequency

Mopping                         Daily                  2
Checking Tissues                Hourly                 1
Cleaning Toilet                 Every Two Hours        1
Clean Building Walled Area      Yearly                 2
Clean Building Mirror Facade    Every Six Months       1
```

So basically the system should be flexible enough to create any intervals and attach this interval to any activities

So if client wants to create a quarterly interval or a fortnightly interval he should be able to configure this in the system

Comment: Can you at least show us some sample data which you need to deal with?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've tried to elaborate with an example ... does this work

Comment: I think you've nailed it.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Please explain "a generic settings table that can take care of the logic" & "the system should be flexible enough". How does a table "take care of the logic"?

Comment: Is this "write only"?  Or will there be `SELECT` statements applied to it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use crond scheduler in linux .[Cron Scehduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Basically you can write the logic behind the functionality and cron will take care. YOu can write cron logic to fire the script in some scheduled time interval.

In case you need more clarification, please let me know in detail.